# How to guarantee field is first JSON field

Tags: json

I want to read JSON without deserializing it first. I want to guarantee that a certain part of the string appears first, like this:

```json
{"first":"part","second":"part"}
```

so that I can do this:

`const messageType = json.slice(2,7); // whatever`

without having to deserialize it.

The only way I can think of to guarantee this is to only have one top level key:

```
    {
    
      first: {key: "part", next: {second: "part"}}
    
    }
```

which would become:

`{"first":{"key":"part","next":{"second":"part"}}}`

Is that the best guarantee, or might there be others?

Actual problem:

I want to deserialize just once, not twice. To figure out the "type" of the object represented by json I have to read one of the json fields (since this is websockets and I can't really use http headers), so I want to read metadata from the json, without having to deserialize it, and then then deserialize just once to the desired specified type (golang)

Comment: Your second example _isn't_ JSON. And even if you only have an object with one top-level property, whitespace can vary such that a positional slice would be fragile. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: Let me add the problem that I want to solve - but I will add here too - I want to deserialize just once, not twice. To figure out the "type" of the object representated by json I have to read one of the json fields (since this is websockets and i can't really use http headers), so I want to read metadata from the json, without having to deserialize it, and then *then* deserialize it to the desired specified type (golang)

Comment: Is deserialising really that expensive?

Comment: What value are you actually trying to extract? `first` or `"part"`?

Comment: If you're trying to parse json with slices then you're doing something inherently wrong.

Comment: @Nick entirely it is

Comment: @Nick I am trying to configure my json so that I know for sure that the first key aka '{"<first>"', is always the first portion of the JSON string, since keys are unordered, I suggested what is in OP but I am open to other ideas

Comment: What you're doing is probably the simplest workaround, although I'm not sure why you need to nest `second` et al rather than having them at the same level as `key` (which you could give the same name as `first` to avoid any possible contention i.e. I would use `{ "first": {"first":"part","second":"part"}}`). Then I would use a regex match (something like `^\s*{\s*"([^"]+)"\s*:` capturing `first` in group 1) so you don't get caught out by changing whitespace in the JSON that is sent to you.